# Wordpress filter: `content_save_pre` hook fails to replace content only with `preg_replace` function

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to replace code block fencing within post_content before save. The post content is written in markdown locally, pushed to github and then Wordpress.

I need the markdown fencing ```` ```js <some code> ``` ```` to be replaced with: `[js] <some code> [/js]` before saving to Wordpress.

See my working repl: https://repl.it/KDz2/1 **My function works perfectly fine outside of Wordpress.**

Wordpress is invoking the function, but for some reason the replace is failing. I know this because I can get a simple `str_replace` to work just fine within Wordpress.

*Issue;*

`preg_replace` is failing to return the replaced content within Wordpress filter. No errors thrown. Why is this failing?

---

*For reference, my functions.php file includes:*

```
add_filter( 'content_save_pre', 'markdown_code_highlight_fence');
function markdown_code_highlight_fence( $content ) {
  $newContent = preg_replace('/^ *(`{3,}|~{3,}) *(\S+)? *\n([\s\S]+?)\s*\1 *(?:\n+|$)/m', '
      [${2}]
      $3
      [\\\${2}]
    ', $content);

  return $newContent;
}
```

*Also tried this*

```
function markdown_code_highlight_fence( $content ) {
  $newContent = preg_replace_callback('/^ *(`{3,}|~{3,}) *(\S+)? *\n([\s\S]+?)\s*\1 *(?:\n+|$)/m', function($match){  
    $lang = $match[2] == '' ? 'js' : $match[2];
    return '
      ['.$lang.']'
      .' '.
      $match[3]
      .' '.
      '[\\'.$lang.']';  }, $content);

  return $newContent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why `preg_replace` isn't working within Wordpress. If anyone can help shed some light, please do.

*In the interim, I have a working solution as follows:*

```
add_filter( 'content_save_pre', 'markdown_code_highlight_fence_replace', 1, 1);
function markdown_code_highlight_fence_replace( $content ) {
  preg_match_all('/`{3,}(\S+)?/', $content, $matches);

  foreach ($matches[1] as $key=>$match) {
    if($match === '') continue;
    $content = preg_replace('/`{3,}/', '[/'.$match.']', $content, 2);
    $content = str_replace('[/'.$match.']'.$match, '['.$match.']', $content);
  }

  return $content;
}
```